# How do I parse GPS Navigation Message on Android

Tags: java, android, gps

Hi I am new to this field and need your help on this.
I want to get the GNSS Ephemeris Data in Android. I don't want  to download it from any website.
This is what I am doing currently:

I am logging the GNSS Navigation Message on Android using GnssNavigationMessage.java (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/GnssNavigationMessage.java).

In my logger I am getting the data using the command:
byte[] data = navigationMessage.getData();

Now the data I am getting looks like this:

Nav,103,769,1,2,1,8,16,-4,19,66,-112,-126,-42,25,20,-8 which follows a header

## Nav,Svid,Type,Status,MessageId,Sub-messageId,Data(Bytes)

I want to get the following parameters for further calculation:

1. PRN     % SV PRN number
2. Toc     % Time of clock (seconds)
3. af0     % SV clock bias (seconds)
4. af1     % SV clock drift (sec/sec)
5. af2     % SV clock drift rate (sec/sec2)
6. IODE    % Issue of data, ephemeris
7. Crs     % Sine harmonic correction to orbit radius (meters)
8. Delta_n % Mean motion difference from computed value (radians/sec)
9. M0      % Mean anomaly at reference time (radians)
10. Cuc     % Cosine harmonic correction to argument of lat (radians)
11. e       % Eccentricity (dimensionless)
12. Cus     % Sine harmonic correction to argument of latitude
    (radians)
13. Asqrt   % Square root of semi-major axis (meters^1/2)
14. Toe     % Reference time of ephemeris (seconds)
15. Cic     % Sine harmonic correction to angle of inclination
    (radians)
16. OMEGA   % Longitude of ascending node at weekly epoch (radians)
17. Cis     % Sine harmonic correction to angle of inclination
    (radians)
18. i0      % Inclination angle at reference time (radians)
19. Crc        % Cosine harmonic correction to the orbit radius
    (meters)
20. omega    % Argument of perigee (radians)
21. OMEGA_DOT% Rate of right ascension (radians/sec)
22. IDOT    % Rate of inclination angle (radians/sec)
23. codeL2  % codes on L2 channel
24. GPS_Week % GPS week (to go with Toe), (NOT Mod 1024)
25. L2Pdata % L2 P data flag
26. accuracy % SV user range accuracy (meters)
27. health  % Satellite health
28. TGD     % Group delay (seconds)
29. IODC    % Issue of Data, Clock
30. ttx       % Transmission time of message (seconds)
31. Fit_interval %fit interval (hours), zero if not known

Please let me know if there is a way to parse the Navigation message which I am receiving to these parameters.
Also let me know if I am going in the wrong direction.
Any lead will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Google has implemented code to parse the navigation message as part of their [GNSSLogger app](https://github.com/google/gps-measurement-tools):

https://github.com/google/gps-measurement-tools/blob/master/GNSSLogger/pseudorange/src/main/java/com/google/location/lbs/gnss/gps/pseudorange/GpsNavigationMessageStore.java

The `GpsNavigationMessageStore` class description says:

```
/**
 * A class to extract the fields of the GPS navigation message from the raw bytes received from the
 * GPS receiver.
 *
 * <p>Raw bytes are passed by calling the method
 * {@link #onNavMessageReported(byte, byte, short, byte[])}
 *
 * <p>A {@link GpsNavMessageProto} containing the extracted field is obtained by calling the method
 * {@link #createDecodedNavMessage()}
 *
 * <p>References:
 * http://www.gps.gov/technical/icwg/IS-GPS-200D.pdf and
 * http://www.gps.gov/technical/ps/1995-SPS-signal-specification.pdf
 *
 */
```